# Can I use build-in intents in german?

Tags: actions-on-google, app-actions

I am looking for an easy solution to launching feature of my app through the "App Action" feature of Google Assistant.

I found info about built-in intents such as `actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE`, but locale is limited to English. Does this mean it only support English utterance? If it is only supports English, can you help me how to use it using German?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you clarify exactly which Built In Intents you were looking to use and how, exactly, you were hoping to use them? While some are English-only, other's have a broader locale. The more details and illustrations you can provide, the better our chances are of being able to help.

Comment: Hi there, actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE is the best fit action within BII. we would like to launching my app and start recording directly with this intent through google assistant. but when I read doc here : https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature, it is limited to English, am I correct? so if it is only available for English, can you suggest me how to approach same feature for German?

Comment: @Prisoner can you help me here?

Comment: Is this a conversational action or an app action?

Comment: @Prisoner App action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature), the `actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE` is currently only available in the following locales:

- en-US
- en-GB
- en-CA
- en-IN
- en-BE
- en-SG
- en-AU

If the locale you want isn't supported - there isn't anything you can do, really. You can try creating a conversational action that will, at some point in the conversation, offer a link that will trigger your app, but this works outside the App Action framework.

Comment: Thanks for update, just check one more that custom intents also doesn't help? actually here in this doucment metioned that only English but wanted to double check with you. https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/custom-intents -"Only the en-US locale is supported for custom intents (device and Assistant language settings must both match)."

Comment: Correct. English only, apparently.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Prisoner. Correct. English only for now.